# Error with react native running android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[Click here to see the image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFNRG.jpg)

I have this error when I run react-native run-android on my device, how can I fix it ?

**I run this**: react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

the app and index file below.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Platform,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View
} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome to React Native!
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      To get started, edit App.js
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      {instructions}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
},
});
```

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('helloworld', () => App);
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? How do you expect anybody to understand what's happening there?

Comment: just click on name pic so you can see

Comment: I know. That is not detail enough

Comment: I ran this code: react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res So after that i tried to run android device so I got this error on my device

Comment: Can you just provide a snippet? Maybe some code in your `App.js`

Comment: Kindly edit your question with the snippet

Comment: I did it, please look what you asked the app.js and index.js

Comment: I hope my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
...
<Text style={styles.instructions}>
  {instructions}
</Text>
...
```

refers to `instructions` is from the boilerplate code generated when you created the app. Usually, this comes before the class definition.

```
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
  'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
  'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
```

Apparently, you removed it and did not remove the corresponding `{instructions}`.

You need to either remove `<Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>` or add code above maybe above your class definition.